# Sharepoint List Event raised when a current view is changed

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, wss-3.0, splistitem, wss

Is there a event which is raised when current view of a SharePoint list is changed. For example the current view displays all items in the list and now the user selects a different view say Added by Me, so is there any event raised in such a condition.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no SharePoint event for view change, for a list of SharePoint events check out this [MSDN Post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408183.aspx), out of these events Site Events, List Events and WebProvisioned event of Web Events are not available for WSS 3.0

What are you trying to achieve with view change event? kindly elaborate, there may be a separate solution without handling SharePoint events

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What i want to achieve is something like this. I want to create a view such that the list is filtered according to the current user information. This information is coming from an external database. So what i was thinking is if there is any view change event then i could write a listener for it, check which view is selected , if it is the said view then fetch current user and his information from external DB and filter the list values. I am a newbie in SharePoint so don't know if such a thing can be done or not. Is there any other way by which this can be achieved?

Comment: I achieved the desired result using custom filter Web part.

Comment: great, sorry did not see your post yesterday